# Do we have enough female users to close questions?

Tags: discussion

On a recent question ["Why does the church appear so male chauvanistic"](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/23691/why-does-the-church-appear-so-male-chauvanistic), a user with a name 'Dan' put a comment

> "It would be very ironic if five men close this question"

I was about to close it but when I saw that comment, I stopped and a thought came to me that we might not have enough female users to close a question. My speculation is that **females have very little interest in theology**. Most women do not want to think much about serious things. It's boring to most of them. They mostly like joyful things only. Women are more interested in listening songs, watching entertainments, romantic movies, TV serials etc.

I'm curious to know how many female users we have.

Do we have enough female users to close questions?

If not, what do you think is the reason why we have less female users?

Comment: The misogyny... it's... blinding.

Comment: I'm almost speechless reading this. I would recommend that you ask some *"females"* at your church if your perception is accurate, but that might be dangerous. Instead, pick up a Bible and read about the theologian **[Priscilla](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts+18:26&version=NIVUK)** who, with her husband, educated none other than Paul. Or the "deacon" **[Phoebe](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans%2016:1&version=NIVUK)**. Or **[Lydia](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts+16:40&version=NIVUK)**'s church.

Comment: The sentiments in your question are at odds with your [good answer](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/23695/62) to that question.

Comment: @Wikis The women in my answer were women of faith. I still doubt that even those women will not participate in Christianity.SE. Believe it or not, **women have more faith** than men but men have more interest in theological studies than women.

Comment: Should I count two downvotes as two female users? Ha Ha

Comment: No, that would be an incorrect assumption. I'm male and downvoted this. Man-to-man I think you're out of line!

Comment: *Drops jaw*... what?

Comment: @Mawia. As a product of living in a sexist society, many women become adept at knowing when a man isn't going to listen to them, and may therefore choose to save their breath.

Comment: Most men don't want to think about serious things either. Just go to work, go home and have a beer, and watch the game on Sunday. Whether male or female, people actually interested in this site (the way it is intended) are few and far between. The only reason it exists is because there are 7 billion people and the magic of the internet can connect all of us into this one spot.

Comment: Actually, I didn't come up with this idea on my own. This speculation is from my wife only. Maybe because we all have different cultures. This is what my wife sees in our society and it is true. Looks like you guys have a great society where your women are interested in theology and are curious enough to participate in Christianity.SE.

Comment: Well, it's cool to have a post with -8 votes. My first time. :p

Comment: As far as doing the roll-up-sleeves work of the church, women are extremely (over?) prevalent. As far as debating theology online, women are nearly absent.

Comment: I think I heard somewhere that most theists in Britain are female. I think women are as interested in 'serious' subjects and men just as subjected to whimzy (I love movies, music, tv etc.) Mind, I'd be careful dissmissing those things as 'whimzy' anyway. Many of the great Greek Philosophers took a great interest in 'the Arts' and Jesus used parables to explain deep concepts.

Answer (score 11):

I remember I asked a similar question in the chatroom. waxeagle, a moderator at the time, said that the reason the Stacks Exchange Network has so little females is that the Stacks Exchange Network used to stem from Stack Overflow, the computer programming Q&A site, and males outnumber females in computer programming.

It is hard to tell who is male and who is female on an Internet forum or website, because all you have are words and perceptions. One way to tell whether an individual is male or female is by going to the individual's profile and reading the individual's snippet about himself or herself.

I am not aware of females' having little or no interest in theology or "serious" matters. Where did you get that?

Comment: That makes sense. (+1) Programmers think much(like myself, he he). This might have some impact on their approach to religion as well. There are of course other non-programming users who are curious about theology, who search on internet and tumbled upon this site. But I still doubt that even among non-programmers, male will still outnumber females.

Comment: @Mawia The suggestion that women do not think much, like Caleb said, also seems to me an insidious flavor of chauvinism.

Answer (score 9):

Ok, let's start with the question. Are there 5 female users of this site with 3k or more reputation capable of casting a close vote? Probably not. Going through the roughly 40 or so users who are capable of casting a close vote none of them are *obviously* female and *most* of them I either know to be male or have a strong idea that they are. However, this is not conclusive. I've not spoken personally to *any* of these people in a context in which I'd know for certain if they were male or female (it's not uncommon for females, especially those in technology to choose male or gender neutral screen names) [[source](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users?page=1&tab=reputation&filter=all)].

That said, our *overall* demographics are strongly female. [About 50:50](https://www.quantcast.com/christianity.stackexchange.com?country=US), reflecting closely the overall population (we bend *slightly* male, the overall population bends *slightly* female). Contrast this to the *overall* Stack Exchange population and you see something *entirely* different. Stack Exchange is about [75:25 M:F](https://www.quantcast.com/stackexchange.com#!demo), in no small part due to the fact that the primary traffic drivers are sites that appeal to a  male dominated profession.

So, while we *may* not have any particularly high rep users who are openly female, they *are here*, so let's remember that and not make ourselves look like donkeys with our hooves firmly fixed in our mouths (And this questions' suppositions certainly do that).

How ridiculous are they? Well enrollment at a mid sized (~1000 students) theological seminary in a denomination that doesn't ordain women (namely mine, the PCA), is [75:25](http://open-site.org/schools/the-covenant-theological-seminary/), some more research has other seminaries reporting similar or higher ratios (I'll provide more links if you'd like).

All of this combines to make the assertion:

> My speculation is that females have very little interest in theology. Most women do not want to think much about serious things. It's boring to most of them. They mostly like joyful things only. Women are more interested in listening songs, watching entertainments, romantic movies, TV serials etc.

…patently ridiculous, and shows signs of either a lack of exposure to actual females or a staid ideal of what womanhood should be. I've had some *very* deep and thoughtful theological conversations of late with my dear wife. Some of my best high-school memories are having rather deep and involved theological discussions on the subjects of reformed theology and infant baptism with several young ladies who were far more interested in the weighty matters of theology than they were in the other things you list (I actually recently got to revisit one of those conversations yesterday with one of those friends).

All that to say, your assertion is easily proved false in the specific and whether or not it's true in the aggregate, making it unsupported is the very kind of thing that makes women feel belittled, and probably at least in part attitudes like this contribute to why women make themselves anonymous on the internet.

Answer (score 7):

First of all the idea that the gender of those voting to close matters in this case seems rather silly the me. The closure is based on the form of the question not the particular subject matter! We close questions of that form all the time.

Secondly the suggestion that females "do not want to think much about serious things" seems to me the be its own insidious flavor of chauvinism, as if women aren't likely to be up for the task anyway. This whole post smells pretty disrespectful actually.

You might want to revisit your own approach, figure out what you hope to accomplish, then weigh the merits of various ways for accomplishing that. 'Cause this is counter productive...

Comment: Please realize my comment was meant in complete humor, I am pretty confident it had a wink that didn't make it when being cited here ;)

Comment: @Dan I have no issue with your comment: you didn't say it mattered, only that it was ironic. I agree it is in fact be ironic. But there is a big difference between seeing it as ironic and seeing it as a problem, then blaming women for the problem.

Comment: I completely agree. Hence my comment on this question :)

Answer (score -3):

I'd be willing to posit that men are more fixated on the minutiae that gets asked around here and that is what drives women away.  But that's because of this football team mentality Christendom is often reduced to because of our fractured churches.

I've got this truth and you've got that truth and my truth trumps your truth, but sometimes you augment your truth with such and such a powerup and othertimes it is deprecated by such and such a heresy.  It's not evangelization it's pokemon, and that's why it's not interesting to humanity or women (of which humanity is a type).

Oh well, that's sort of the point of the site, and I don't think it's going to change.  It might implode, I guess that's a change.

Comment: What is pokemon? A Japanese cartoon? I enjoyed watching that Anime series. :)